# what should i do to run selenium chrome in docker?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

wanted to add selenium chromium into my docker but i am not sure what is the correct way to do it.

here is my current dockerfile

```
# Dockerfile.prod

FROM tiangolo/uvicorn-gunicorn:python3.8-slim

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y netcat

COPY requirements.txt .
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

COPY . .
```

and my python code for selenium

```
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC


user_agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) ' \
    'Chrome/80.0.3987.132 Safari/537.36'


def start_selenium_chrome(url, site):
    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    options.add_argument("start-maximized")
    options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
    options.add_argument('--incognito')
    options.add_argument('--headless')
    options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
    options.add_argument(f'user-agent={user_agent}')
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install(), chrome_options=options)

    driver.get(url)

    return driver.page_source
```

working fine on my local machine which is windows but not in docker, when i try it on my docker server, it does not work but i am sure i need to do something on the dockerfile first to install selenium before using it.

not sure what is the correct command to have in this case.

here is my docker error message

```
web_1      | ====== WebDriver manager ======
web_1      | Could not get version for google-chrome with the any command: google-chrome --version || google-chrome-stable --version
web_1      | Current google-chrome version is UNKNOWN
web_1      | Get LATEST chromedriver version for UNKNOWN google-chrome
web_1      | There is no [linux64] chromedriver for browser  in cache
web_1      | Trying to download new driver from https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/98.0.4758.80/chromedriver_linux64.zip
web_1      | Driver has been saved in cache [/root/.wdm/drivers/chromedriver/linux64/98.0.4758.80]
web_1      | 172.20.0.3:37694 - "GET /api/test/search/Damnation HTTP/1.1" 500
web_1      | [2022-02-05 01:05:41 +0000] [14] [ERROR] Exception in ASGI application
web_1      | Traceback (most recent call last):
web_1      |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/uvicorn/protocols/http/httptools_impl.py", line 375, in run_asgi
web_1      |     result = await app(self.scope, self.receive, self.send)
web_1      |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/uvicorn/middleware/proxy_headers.py", line 75, in __call__
web_1      |     return await self.app(scope, receive, send)
web_1      |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/fastapi/applications.py", line 212, in __call__        
web_1      |     await super().__call__(scope, receive, send)
web_1      |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/starlette/applications.py", line 112, in __call__      
web_1      |     await self.middleware_stack(scope, receive, send)
web_1      |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/starlette/middleware/errors.py", line 181, in __call__ 
web_1      |     raise exc
web_1      |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/starlette/middleware/errors.py", line 159, in __call__ 
web_1      |     await self.app(scope, receive, _send)
web_1      |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/starlette/exceptions.py", line 82, in __call__
web_1      |     raise exc
web_1      |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/starlette/exceptions.py", line 71, in __call__
web_1      |     await self.app(scope, receive, sender)
web_1      |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/starlette/routing.py", line 656, in __call__
web_1      |     await route.handle(scope, receive, send)
web_1      |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/starlette/routing.py", line 259, in handle
web_1      |     await self.app(scope, receive, send)
web_1      |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/starlette/routing.py", line 61, in app
web_1      |     response = await func(request)
web_1      |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/fastapi/routing.py", line 226, in app
web_1      |     raw_response = await run_endpoint_function(
web_1      |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/fastapi/routing.py", line 159, in run_endpoint_functionweb_1      |     return await dependant.call(**values)
web_1      |   File "/app/app/main.py", line 40, in get_test_price
web_1      |     return await search_test_price(cardName)
web_1      |   File "/app/app/util.py", line 34, in search_test_price
web_1      |     return get_from_test(card_name)
web_1      |   File "/app/app/test.py", line 25, in get_from_test
web_1      |     page_source = start_selenium_chrome(settings.test.test_SEARCH_URL+card_name, 'testing')
traefik_1  | 161.142.225.194 - - [05/Feb/2022:01:05:38 +0000] "GET /api/test/search/Damnation HTTP/2.0" 500 21 "-" "-" 10874 "fastapi@docker" "http://172.20.0.2:80" 2044ms
web_1      |   File "/app/app/scrape.py", line 20, in start_selenium_chrome
web_1      |     driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install(), chrome_options=options)
web_1      |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 70, in __init__
web_1      |     super(WebDriver, self).__init__(DesiredCapabilities.CHROME['browserName'], "goog",
web_1      |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chromium/webdriver.py", line 90, in 
__init__
web_1      |     self.service.start()
web_1      |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 98, in start
web_1      |     self.assert_process_still_running()
web_1      |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 110, in assert_process_still_running
web_1      |     raise WebDriverException(
web_1      | selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Service /root/.wdm/drivers/chromedriver/linux64/98.0.4758.80/chromedriver unexpectedly exited. Status code was: 127
```

Comment: _but not in docker_: What error do you see?

Comment: edited my original post with my docker error message from the logs

Comment: You have to install chrome browser.
Take a look at this docker file https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/docker-selenium/blob/trunk/NodeChrome/Dockerfile.

Comment: Step 11/16 : COPY wrap_chrome_binary /opt/bin/wrap_chrome_binary
ERROR: Service 'web' failed to build: COPY failed: file not found in build context or excluded by .dockerignore: stat wrap_chrome_binary: file does not exist

getting an error for this section